# Numpy Meshgrid Error: Unsupported Operand Types

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Currently playing around with the 3d plotting capabilities of matplotlib. I have a data file filled up with some... well... data. Let's say it has angle data, order data, and intensity data. I want to make a contour plot of order on the x-axis, angle on the y-axis, and intensity as the color. I fill up arrays `orders` and `angles` with their values, and `ints` is a two-dimensional array of dimensions `len(orders)xlen(angles)`. When I do this:

```
orders = np.array(orders)
angles = np.array(angles)
Orders, Angles = np.meshgrid(orders, angles)
ints = np.array(ints)
```

The error:

```
/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.pyc in meshgrid(*xi, **kwargs)
   3377         if copy_:
   3378             mult_fact = np.ones(shape, dtype=int)
-> 3379             return [x * mult_fact for x in output]
   3380         else:
   3381             return np.broadcast_arrays(*output)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Pretty confused, as I do believe I'm using the meshgrid function properly. Any idea what's going on here? On a related note, if I get this working properly, will:

```
ax.contourf(Angles, Orders, ints)
```

produce the result I'm looking for (where `ax` is my `Axes3D` object)?

EDIT: As requested, here is some sample data. Printing `angles` provides:

```
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77', '78', '79', '80', '81', '82', '83', '84', '85', '86', '87', '88', '89', '90', '91', '92', '93', '94', '95', '96', '97', '98', '99', '100', '101', '102', '103', '104', '105', '106', '107', '108', '109', '110', '111', '112', '113', '114', '115', '116', '117', '118', '119', '120', '121', '122', '123', '124', '125', '126', '127', '128', '129', '130', '131', '132', '133', '134', '135', '136', '137', '138', '139', '140', '141', '142', '143', '144', '145', '146', '147', '148', '149', '150', '151', '152', '153', '154', '155', '156', '157', '158', '159', '160', '161', '162', '163', '164', '165', '166', '167', '168', '169', '170', '171', '172', '173', '174', '175', '176', '177', '178', '179', '180', '181', '182', '183', '184', '185', '186', '187', '188', '189', '190', '191', '192', '193', '194', '195', '196', '197', '198', '199', '200', '201', '202', '203', '204', '205', '206', '207', '208', '209', '210', '211', '212', '213', '214', '215', '216', '217', '218', '219', '220', '221', '222', '223', '224', '225', '226', '227', '228', '229', '230', '231', '232', '233', '234', '235', '236', '237', '238', '239', '240', '241', '242', '243', '244', '245', '246', '247', '248', '249', '250', '251', '252', '253', '254', '255', '256', '257', '258', '259', '260', '261', '262', '263', '264', '265', '266', '267', '268', '269', '270', '271', '272', '273', '274', '275', '276', '277', '278', '279', '280', '281', '282', '283', '284', '285', '286', '287', '288', '289', '290', '291', '292', '293', '294', '295', '296', '297', '298', '299', '300', '301', '302', '303', '304', '305', '306', '307', '308', '309', '310', '311', '312', '313', '314', '315', '316', '317', '318', '319', '320', '321', '322', '323', '324', '325', '326', '327', '328', '329', '330', '331', '332', '333', '334', '335', '336', '337', '338', '339', '340', '341', '342', '343', '344', '345', '346', '347', '348', '349', '350', '351', '352', '353', '354', '355', '356', '357', '358', '359', '360']
```

And printing orders:

```
['6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77', '78', '79', '80', '81', '82', '83', '84', '85', '86', '87', '88', '89', '90', '91', '92', '93', '94', '95', '96', '97', '98', '99']
```

so I don't think it's a problem with converting these arrays to `ndarray`'s

double edit: Welp, I'm stupid -- as simple as converting the data I'm reading from my files to floats before putting them in their arrays.

Comment: Could you post some sample data which produces the error? Your code seems to work fine if `orders` and `angles` hold 1d numeric arrays.

Comment: Please post an answer with your second edit.